# What C or C++ tool is used to automatically generate WSDL in SOA project?

Tags: c++, web-services

Suppose in fairly large SOA project I am tasked with developing  Web Service  in C++. I am looking for tools that would automatically generate WSDL ((both REST and SOAP))and XML Schema for this web service that I have implemented in C++ resulting in several classes and their methods.. Are there such tools that would completely automate this process? Or at least part of WSDL and XML Schema would still need to be authored manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[gsoap](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html) is a soap framework for C/C++. It comes with a nice tool that completely automates he task of creating the wsdl files from a header file.

Comment: Keep in mind that the sources generated by `wsdl2h` and `soapcpp2` are licensed GPLv2. That effectively means that you need to release the whole application using these sources as GPLv2 or pay Genivia for a commercial license. I'm forced to use gSOAP in a project right now and can't say I'm a fan : I certainly wouldn't pay to use it.